# TortoiseSVN Commits failing:  "The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable", "Attempt to write a readonly database"

Tags: svn, tortoise-svn

I have been using tortoise svn for a couple weeks now.

I get errors very often. Almost everything I do creates an error. this is with repositories on the internet, locally on my machine or a machine on the network. So I started to keep track. Some examples are below.

> 12/31/2010
>
> Can't move
>   'C:\Users\jisaacks\Desktop\my branch
>   test.svn\tmp\entries' to 
>   'C:\Users\jisaacks\Desktop\my branch
>   test.svn\entries': The file or
>   directory is corrupted and unreadable.
>
> 01/04/2011
>
> Commit failed (details follow): Server
>   sent unexpected return value (405
>   Method Not Allowed) in response to
>   MKCOL request for
>   '/svn/kranichs-svn/!svn/wrk/b316f15e-0869-4644-9c53-87aa0103506b/branches'
>
> 01/06/2011
>
> Can't move
>   'C:\Users\jisaacks\Desktop\DVD
>   Catalog\vendors.svn\tmp\entries' to
>   'C:\Users\jisaacks\Desktop\DVD
>   Catalog\vendors.svn\entries': The
>   file or directory is corrupted and
>   unreadable.
>
> 01/06/2011
>
> Can't move
>   'C:\Users\jisaacks\Desktop\DVD
>   Catalog\cake\tests\test_app\views\layouts.svn\tmp\entries'
>   to 'C:\Users\jisaacks\Desktop\DVD
>   Catalog\cake\tests\test_app\views\layouts.svn\entries':
>   The file or directory is corrupted and
>   unreadable.
>
> 01/06/2011
>
> Commit failed (details follow):
>   attempt to write a readonly database
>   attempt to write a readonly database

That last one about the read only database happens every time I commit. Say if I am working on the head revision (7) in a working copy. I make a change and commit it. It gives me this error. But if I look at the log it tells me that there is now a revision 8 (the commit I just made) but I am still on revision 7. So I need to run update to be on the current revision that I just commited. I hope I explained that clearly.

Anyways with all these errors I wonder.. Is TSVN just this unstable, does everyone have these issues. Or is it just me? If just me, what could I be doing wrong?

Comment: What is giving you the copy errors?  It sounds like Windows, not Tortoise.  If the server is giving you errors (405, writing to a read-only db), there might be something wrong with it.

Comment: Are you running Win7?  From a [ServerFault question](http://serverfault.com/questions/72561/64-bit-tortoisesvn-on-windows-7-says-file-or-directory-is-corrupted-and-unreadab), apparently Windows 7 has problems copying svn directories.  The fix was released a while ago; are you updated?

Comment: @Nick yes I am on win7 I will update my version of TSVN and see if that helps. Thanks.

Comment: @Nick I updated my version of TSVN, I am not getting the error when I commit tho, however I still need to update after a commit to be on the current Revision I just created.

Answer (score 4):

I have seen this problem on a colleague's PC, it turned out that it was Microsoft Security Essentials corrupting the files downloaded by TortoiseSVN. As soon as we disabled it, the problem disappeared and the SVN checkout was fine.

I suggest to temporarily disable your antivirus and try again.

Comment: I will try this next week when our system admin is back in the office. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Today I also got the following error:

```
svn: E200031: attempt to write a readonly database
```

The solution (found [here](http://h3x.no/2010/12/04/svn-gives-attempt-to-write-a-readonly-database-error)) was to go to the svn server and and fix **the permissions of rep-cache.db in the project's db folder** (e.g. /svn/my_project/db/rep-cache.db)

Note that rep-cache.db was hidden from a regular *ls* but was exposed in FileZilla.

The following 2 commands solved the problem:

```
sudo chown root:root rep-cache.db
sudo chmod 777 rep-cache.db
```

Note that these are not *safe* permissions, but they did the trick.

Interestingly enough the file *rep-cache.db* does not seem to exist in our other projects.

Comment: Thank you! Got this same strange error today with a seldom used repo. The rep-cache.db file was owned by root:apache instead of apache:apache. I changed the owner only (not permissions), and the problem went away. Interestingly, we could commit empty, zero-byte files, but files with any content were blocked with the "readyonly database" error.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue.
After some searching on the internet found [this article](http://h3x.no/2010/12/04/svn-gives-attempt-to-write-a-readonly-database-error).
Then realized that I was logged as a user different from the user that I had used to setup svn under, a permission issue basically.

Update: Adding more information so the answer is complete without the article too.

Basically, I had setup/installed the svn using root user and the default user on many linux systems is other than root. So when I logged into the system I was not root, hence I was getting the above issue. sudo su, was required to login as root and everything worked

Comment: Can you summarize that link, so that if it goes dead, your answer is still useful?